# Выскакивает div

Tags: html, css3

Почему из за большего кол-ва текста, в div с надписью "Не рабочее время в это воскресенье" выскакивает вверх, понимаю что из за  количества текста в div, но почему так происходит?

```css
.time-element {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: red;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 margin: 1px;
 font-size: x-small;
 text-align: center; 

}
 .time-lunch{
 background-color: green;
}

.time-accept{
 background-color: blue;
}

.time-select{
 width: 85px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="timepicker"><div class="time-element time-lunch time-select">Обед</div><div class="time-element time-accept time-select">Рабочее время</div><div class="time-element time-select">Не рабочее время в это воскресенье </div><div class="time-element">6</div><div class="time-element">7</div><div class="time-element">8</div><div class="time-element">9</div><div class="time-element">10</div><div class="time-element">11</div><div class="time-element">12</div><div class="time-element">13</div><div class="time-element">14</div><div class="time-element">15</div><div class="time-element">16</div><div class="time-element">17</div><div class="time-element">18</div><div class="time-element">19</div><div class="time-element">20</div><div class="time-element">21</div><div class="time-element">22</div></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По умолчанию `inline-block` элементы выравниваются по базовой линии текста. Для решения вашей проблемы используйте свойство `vertical-align`

```css
.time-element {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: red;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 margin: 1px;
 font-size: x-small;
 text-align: center;
  /*решение*/
  vertical-align:top;

}
 .time-lunch{
 background-color: green;
}

.time-accept{
 background-color: blue;
}

.time-select{
 width: 85px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="timepicker"><div class="time-element time-lunch time-select">Обед</div><div class="time-element time-accept time-select">Рабочее время</div><div class="time-element time-select">Не рабочее время в это воскресенье </div><div class="time-element">6</div><div class="time-element">7</div><div class="time-element">8</div><div class="time-element">9</div><div class="time-element">10</div><div class="time-element">11</div><div class="time-element">12</div><div class="time-element">13</div><div class="time-element">14</div><div class="time-element">15</div><div class="time-element">16</div><div class="time-element">17</div><div class="time-element">18</div><div class="time-element">19</div><div class="time-element">20</div><div class="time-element">21</div><div class="time-element">22</div></div>
```